# Did a king ask for a ball? How did 王 + 求 become 球?

Tags: glyph-origin

The character 球 means *ball* and is composed of

1. 王 meaning *king* and
2. 求 meaning *demand*.

Where does this composition come from? Did a king ask for a ball?

Comment: @jogloran gave a great answer, but I also wanted to point out that in general, most characters should not be analyzed via the meaning of their components. In fact over 90% of characters are [phono-semantic compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Phono-semantic_compound_characters), in which one component hints at the meaning while the other hints at the pronunciation, as is the case here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope. The radical was simplified from 玉 (jade), originally referring to a polished sphere of jade. 求 is the phonetic component.

For reference, Baxter's Old Chinese reconstruction has 求 *grju, and 球 *grju. In this particular case, 求 has remained a good phonetic for three millennia!

The sense of 'sounding stone made of jade' can be seen in the Kangxi dictionary: http://www.kangxizidian.com/kangxi/0732.gif

Comment: Brilliant answer.